# DirectX on Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: directx

I have installed Windows SDK on my Windows 10 laptop. However, there are assembly references to Microsoft.DirectX, Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D, Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX and Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput in my code. These are generating the error - The type or namespace name directx does not exist in the namespace Microsoft when i compile my code. Do I have to point my code to the directx header files that are installed within the Windows SDK. These are available at C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt\impl. If so, how do I point my code there. The directx files there are Windows.Graphics.DirectX.0, Windows.Graphics.DirectX.1 and so on and so forth. Should these be referenced instead of Microsoft.DirectX, Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D, Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX and Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput. If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft.DirectX.* assemblies are the legacy Managed DX 1.1 assemblies that only shipped in the legacy DirectX SDK. They have nothing at all to do with the Windows Runtime APIs or C++/WinRT language projections. They never shipped in any Windows 10 SDK and are only deployed by the legacy DXSETUP package.

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/directx-and-net/) and [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/dxsetup-update/).

A recommended replacement is to use [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) or [SlimDX](https://code.google.com/archive/p/slimdx/).

> SlimDX is no longer an active project, but it is still a good option for a direct replacement of legacy Managed DX 1.1

Comment: Ok. I was not able to download slimdx from the link you have given. If I install either of them, how do I then change my code to use DirectX in a C# code? Can I then add these references - Microsoft.DirectX, Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D, Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3DX and Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput ? If so, how ?

Comment: SlimDX is a direct re-implementation of the original Microsoft.DirectX assemblies, so porting should be trivial for that one. SharpDX is more modern and is a 'direct projection' of the DirectX API.